# Win32_NTLogEvent query rendering data with 1 hour latency with event viewer

Tags: windows-event-log, wmi, eventviewer

Trying to collect the event log data with WMI query using class Win32_NTLogEvent.But this is not sync with event viewer data.The WMI query rendering data with 1 hour latency with event viewer.Hence unable to collect the as per poll interval.
This is observed in windows 2016 data-center server
The timezone and date-time -settings are proper.
Kindly let me know whether any one experienced similar situation and is there any solution for the same.

Comment: What is the output of `wmic computersystem get currenttimezone` ?

Comment: The above command output : CurrentTimeZone
330   But from the date and time settings Its UTC +5.30 shown...

Comment: "wmic timezone get caption " outputs  (UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi

Comment: Are you running wmic and event viewer local or remote?

Comment: Both wmic and event viewer running in local-host only....not from remote